# (Docker) How to install dependencies, using separate Composer container, in WordPress container?

Tags: wordpress, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

## Dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress

ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-08-12

ADD \
  composer.json /var/www/html
ADD \
  composer.lock /var/www/html

# install the PHP extensions
RUN \
  apt-get -qq update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y vim wget && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Symlink User's "wp-content" folder into the newly installed Wordpress
RUN \
  rm -rf /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/* && \
  rm -rf /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/themes/* && \
  cp -fr /usr/src/wordpress/* /var/www/html/ && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/

# volume for mysql database and wordpress install
VOLUME ["/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins", "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes"]

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80 3306

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

## Docker Compose File

```
wordpress:
  build: .
  links:
    - mysql
    - composer
  volumes:
    - wp-content/plugins/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
    - wp-content/themes/:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
  environment:
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=__WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD__
    - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=__WORDPRESS_DB_NAME__
    # - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=__WORDPRESS_DB_USER__

  ports:
    - "9888:80"

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=__WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD__
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=__WORDPRESS_DB_NAME__

composer:
  image: composer/composer
```

## Question details

I'm able to `ADD` the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files to the working directory. I can confirm that these two files are in the working directory.

What I need is for the Dockerfile (or wherever) to also automatically install the dependencies into the working directory.

According to Docker Hub, https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/,
I should be able to `docker run -v $(pwd):/app composer/composer install` to install the dependencies but how do I do this in Dockerfile?

Also I'm confused because the `-v` flag, https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/, has to do with mounting the specified host directory into the a container but I've already `ADD`ed the necessary files to the working directory. All I want to do is install the dependencies.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to mount the current directory to `/app` when running your `composer` container. I've put together a simple example to illustrate this working at https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/e2c428f2cd234b718239.

The key parts here are the `volumes` for the `composer` part of the application and the `restart: 'yes'` on the primary PHP application (the application likely will not run until Composer has run so you will want it to restart).

Comment: Thank you so much Andy! Works wonderfully well.

How does volume mounting work? When I `docker run -i -t platform_wordpress /bin/bash` to look at the working directory files in the container, I notice that the plugin files don't exist here, but exist in my host(vagrant) directory.

I was having a hard time finding answers in Docker docs. Do you have any links for in depth answers regarding Docker Compose and Docker fundamentals.

Thanks again. :-D

Comment: Also, where can I read more about `restart`. I'm unable to find that in the Docker Compose docs.
Did you figure out that the primary app needed to be restarted through experimentation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "plugin files not existing". You should probably ask another question for that. The `restart` option is in the docs at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cpu-shares-cpuset-domainname-entrypoint-hostname-ipc-mac-address-mem-limit-memswap-limit-privileged-read-only-restart-stdin-open-tty-user-working-dir. It is part of the Docker run command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart. I supposed Docker Compose options 'yes' and 'no' translate to 'always' and 'never' respectively.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add dependencies to the actual container, so doing this in a CI and pushing the app container won't include the dependencies.