# How does Composer (PHP) fit into a Docker workflow?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I'm looking to understand the best practice for fitting Composer (PHP) into my Docker WordPress development workflow.

I've just started using Docker for PHP/WordPress development as well as Composer. It's a bit of a steep learning curve but it all seems to make sense so far as I work through lots of guides and tutorials.

I have Docker working and (I think) a good understanding of how/why to use it. I understand a benefit of Docker is that I don't need to modify my host OS i.e. installing PHP and Composer and also that it makes it easy to move around since it includes everything required. Lots of tutorials seem to have Composer and PHP installed on the host OS as the first step for setting up a project is using Composer to pull down something like Roots Bedrock on the host OS and then using this directory as a volume in Docker. From what I understand so far this isn't the best way to do it as I'm modifying the host OS and the project container doesn't include everything required to run.

My best guess at a better way is a dedicated Composer container that has my entire project directory (containing all my different projects) as a volume. I can then run Composer commands in this container on the appropriate project directory. My sticking point on this is that again each project container doesn't include everything required to run (Composer). So my next idea is that each project should have a Composer container of its own. This would result in each project having the following containers: WordPress official image, MariaDB, phpMyAdmin, Composer. I'm not sure if this makes each project overkill with 4 containers?

If anyone is able to advise on the best practice way to do this and the reasons why I'd really appreciate it! Thanks! :)

Comment: A while ago I put together an example of this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215978/684908. I think the gist is still relevant. However, the general question is a bit vague and hard to answer because the correct workflow for you may not be the same for someone else.

Comment: Why not simply use a Docker image for development that contains both your source code **and** Composer? That is one more file

Comment: @NicoHaase Do you mean rather than using the WordPress image (which contains PHP) use something like an Nginx image and add Composer to that? Sorry I'm still really new to this workflow so don't entirely understand.

Comment: @AndyShinn Thanks for this! I'm reading through at the moment. It sounds like this is its own dedicated Composer container that I just start up with a volume for the current project I'm working on and then swap the volume when I need to work on a different project? Appreciate the help. Just looking for a good best practice starting point.

Comment: Simply extend the Wordpress image, install Composer to it and you're done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am following you right, you want to be able to install and run php composer packages in your wordpress php project.

If you are using a macOS or Linux, there is a really handy thing called [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Which will make your life a whole lot easier managing and updating packages on your system; such as node, composer, etc.

Follow the simple installation guide at https://brew.sh/ to install hidden packages.

My experience of [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) php packages in wordpress, you have to upload these packages (the vendor folder) to the server (in your theme folder), so you can use them via the `autoload.php` file. *Unlike node and javascript where only the required modules you use are compiled into a single file.*

So i'm pretty sure you don't need to make an extra container in docker to handle this, because how would you deploy the composer packages to your production environment, this just over complicates things with wordpress. Plus more containers may slow down your local environment.

Treat each project as it's own using `composer.json` to manage packages in the current project.

---

How I use composer is like this (once you have installed [homebrew](https://brew.sh/))...

Find a php package you wana use, for example [Netspot Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Which is also on [packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon](https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon).

In your local project wp theme directory, run the package installation command...

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

This will then create these files and folders (not the .gitignore file) in your theme directory.

[image]

You can install as many packages as you need using this method.

If you look in the `composer.json` file you will see this json array...

```
{
    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.36"
    }
}
```

So if you want to remove a composer package, simply take the `vendor/package` key from the json array and run it like this...

```
composer remove nesbot/carbon
```

Ideally don't manually edit the `composer.json` file. Use the composer commands to build this file.

So now you got some composer package(s) installed, you need to load them into your theme.

In your `functions.php` at the top, or anywhere before where you intend to call your packages, add this php code...

```
// load our composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This `autoload.php` file is generated via composer and loads all your installed packages and package dependencies,

Now you can use a package in your theme php like this... ([Netspot Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) example)

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$time = Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($cart['updated']['time'],'Asia/Dubai');
```

Also you **never** need to upload `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files to your server. You only need to deploy the `vendor` folder.

And you **never** need to commit the `vendor` folder, you only need to commit `composer.json`. With this json file you can easily re-build the `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file using this command...

```
composer install
```

...handy when pulling your project to another computer.

The vendor folder can be quite heavy and is pointless having version control on it (git) as the `composer.json` saves the current package versions.